# How to go to next action if some condition fails in Python or Autoit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, autoit

I am using the following pyautoit (Python + Autoit) code to automate the windows app installation.

My requirement is , Script should wait for 30 seconds for a window to appear. If window appears it should raise exception. Else it should go to next action.

Following code raises exception when the window appears. But when window NOT appears its not going to next step. Its throws "AutoItError: timeout on wait for activate window". I don't want to get through this error. Simply its should go to next action.

Code :

```
    if autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:TESTINH]", 30) == 0:
        raise Exception("Env is DOWN...!!!")
    else:    
        autoit.send("{TAB}")
        autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Not familiar with autoit, but have you tried a smaller wait time? The example(s) in the docs use a wait time of only a few seconds.

Comment: @Nuclearman I have tried with 1, 2, 3. 4 and 5 seconds.. Same issue.. Can u please tell me, which example(s) you are referring to?

Comment: It could also be a bug or something. I'd add at as [an issue on their github](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit/issues). You'll probably have better luck asking there anyway.

Comment: @Nuclearman Thanks. Let me ask in github

Comment: It seems like a legit error handling working as designed. You have to catch the timeout exception from AutoIt. And raise your Python exception afterwards. But try to debug the function first to see the output once the window is found. Probably your code isn't semantically valid yet. I think you cannot expect the very same result (0 as you assume) from the pyautoit wrapper functions or assume they behave exactly as the AutoIt pendants would do. And test your send-functions without the `autoit.win_w...` whether they work on their own (include a few seconds delay to manually activate the window).

Answer (score 0):

That could help:

```
wwa = autoit.winwaitactive("[CLASS:TESTINH]", 30)

if(wwa == 0):
    raise Exception("Env is DOWN...!!!")

else:
    autoit.send("{TAB}")
    autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do in AutoIt. You need to check the @error macro.

```
; Wait up to 30 seconds window to appear.
WinWait("[CLASS:TESTINH]", "", 30)

;check to see if there was a WinWait error/the window never came up
If @error Then 
  MsgBox(0, "", "The window was NOT found!")
Else
  MsgBox(0, "", "The window was found.")
;do something....
EndIf
```

Or you could do it this way...

```
;Wait up to 30 seconds window to appear.
If WinWait("[CLASS:TESTINH]", "", 30) <> @error Then
  ;do something....
EndIf
```